# How to show $2$ and $3$ are generators of the additive group $Z/(5)$.

Tags: cyclic-groups

This may sound like an easy question, but I never learned cyclic groups due to my time constraint of my class and that the professor ran out of time to teach it. However, he left me with a problem to solve. The question is "Show that both $2$ and $3$ are generators of the additive group $Z/(5)$. I know that a cyclic group is a group that has one element that can generate other elements of the same form in that group. But how do I show with $2$ and $3$. I thought about showing $(2+3)^n$ would make that the generator of $Z/(5)$. Is that correct? If not, can someone explain to me how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean generators of $\;\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\;$ , many times denoted by $\;\Bbb Z_5\;$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$\Bbb Z=\langle 2,3\rangle\implies \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z=\langle 2+5\Bbb Z,\,3+5\Bbb Z\rangle$$

Everything, of course, additive. Of course, you **don't** need two generators of either group, but you can use two generators.

Comment: Would it be the same if I did $⟨2*5Z,3*5Z⟩$ if it was the multiplicative group of the field $Z/(5)$?

Comment: @HenryLee No as $\;2\cdot5\Bbb Z\;$ is not even an element of $\;\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\;$ ...

Comment: How would I do it for the multiplicative group?

Comment: @HenryLee It's just the same exactly: $$\left(\Bbb Z_5\right)^*=\langle 2+5\Bbb Z,\,3+5\Bbb Z\rangle=\langle 2+5\Bbb Z\rangle$$ If you want two generators choose first option, if you want only one choose the second one

Comment: I'm asking for the multiplicative group of $Z/5$.

Comment: @HenryLee That's **exactly** what I answered in my past comment...

Comment: $⟨2+5Z⟩$ does not generate the entire field of $Z/(5)$

Comment: @HenryLee True, it doesn't. It just generates the multiplicative **group** $\;\Bbb Z_5^*\;$ ,as you asked in your second comment below my answer.

Comment: Then I'm confused, What is a multiplicative group of a $Z_5$. Sorry, I'm new with group theory.

Comment: @HenryLee Is the set of all elements of the field **different from zero**. When this set is finite we get a cyclic group, as in this case. But we also have multiplicative groups with the more well known fields: $\;\Bbb Q^*\,,\,\,\Bbb R^*\;,\;\;\Bbb C^*\;$ and etc., though these last ones are **not** cyclic (but any *finite* subgroup of them is)

Comment: I need to restate the question. The question says "Let {$1,2,3,4$} be the  multiplicative group of the field $Z/(5)$. Show that this group is cyclic by showing that $2$ is a generator of the group. Show that $3$ also generates the group.

Comment: @HenryLee That's the question I understood all along and the one I addressed and answered...Take into account that in *this* case $\;\{1,2,3,4\}\;$ is **not** a subset of the natural numbers but in fact a set of representatives of equivalence clases modulo $\;5\;$ different from the equiv. class corresponding to zero. Sometimes these are written as $\;\{\overline1,\,\overline2,...\}\;$ . As already mentioned, this group is cyclic since the field is finite, and since (doing arithmetic modulo five): $\;2,2^2=4=-1,\,2^3=8=3,\,2^4=1\;$, we see $\;\langle\overline2\rangle\;$ indeed generates .

Answer (score 0):

Simplest proof: $2, 2+2=4, 2+2+2=1, 2+2+2+2=3, 2+2+2+2+2=0$.  Hence $2$ generates the additive group $Z/(5)$, which has 5 elements.  The proof that $3$ generates it is similar.